# MY QUERY IS GIVING Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

```
select doctor.Doc_Name from doctor 
where doctor.Dept_id=(select department.Dept_No from department where department.Estd_Date>='2013-03-10');
```

I know we can do this query by join/constraint but that is not my question.
I wanted to know if there is a way where I can do this query using nested subqueries?

Comment: Please don't substantially change the question after an answer has been given.  Also please review [ask].

Answer (score 1):

As the message says, your subquery

```
SELECT department.Dept_No FROM department WHERE department.Estd_Date >= '2013-03-10'
```

is returning more than one row.  You need to use `IN` instead of `=` where matching more than one value:

```
SELECT doctor.Doc_Name FROM doctor 
WHERE doctor.Dept_id IN (SELECT department.Dept_No FROM department WHERE department.Estd_Date >= '2013-03-10');
```